# Simpler method for defining tableview data with many columns?

Tags: java, javafx

I'll try to explain this as best I can. I've only started looking into JavaFX for the first time this past week.  I'm still grasping how to use PropertyValueFactory and SimpleStringProperty, but I make it work.   Now, if I have 20 columns that's 20  get/set methods I'd need to write. Not a huge issue, but tedious and seems long-winded to me.

Is there a way I can have all the columns call the same method for data retrieval but pass in a variable? Like either a String or an enum?  So the object in my TableView's ObservableList would have a method like:

```
class TableObject{
    public String getTableElement(String key){ 
        return this.data.get(key);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense, I wasn't quite sure how to word this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your own `Callback` and replace the `PropertyValueFactory`.

```
private static TableColumn<TableObject, String> createColumn(String name, final String key) {
    TableColumn<TableObject, String> column = new TableColumn<>(name);
    column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().getTableElement(key)));
    return column;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. JavaFX is a lot more different than I expected, but seems more powerful